# .htaccess - redirect if page not found

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, drupal

I've spent a lot of time searching for a solution to this. I've tried various scenarious, but to no avail...

I have migrated my blog from WordPress to Drupal. Most of the links are ok, but there are few that aren't.

I would like to redirect all blog pages that are **not** found to the blog root.

Ex.
old (broken) link - `www.mydomain.com/blog/my-old-article` should redirect to 
new link - `www.mydomain/blog`

But if `www.mydomain.com/blog/my-old-article` exists, then it should be displayed.

Is this possible using .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be done in Drupal itself. Because the apache webserver does not know about the database entries of your blog articles.

Comment: Thank you. I guess this would be the best approach. I thought I will get out easy...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `ErrorDocument` line at top:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /
```